# Parameterize Select query in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

In Oracle

I have found that we can't write a `select` statement in a stored procedure.

But I guess it must have an alternative. Any suggestions?

My try

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE DEL as
BEGIN
  select * from CMN_MST;
end;
```

`Error(3,3): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`

Comment: What did you try?  Stored Procedure allow you to write select statements.

Comment: It is showing error... Oracle does not allow select query in stored procedure

Comment: If you post a very short sample, someone will help.

Comment: To execute a query/command in a stored proc, you generally need to tell the server "Hey, the next bit should be run as a statement!" (I don't know how to do it in Oracle off-hand, but documentation and examples abound).  You can absolutely do dynamic statements in stored procedures (in fact, some people recommend in applications only calling sprocs, which do the actual data access).  So what does your proc look like, and what is the full text of the error you're getting?

Comment: Have a look at the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm) or from [Tech-on-the-net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php)

Comment: Update my Queston.. have a look plz

Comment: OK, so what do you want to do with the data you've selected? If you were getting a single row back you could [put it in a variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS1325), but as you appear to expect multiple rows, you can have a cursor that loops over them, or you can put them in a collection, or even return them to the caller. We can't really guess what your aim is here.

Comment: I want to populate Datatable or dataset in .net .. using strored procedure... as we do in sqlserver.

Answer (score 1):

Look the error message it says you need an into clause

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE DEL as
  l_record cmn_mst%rowtype;
BEGIN
  select * 
  into l_record 
  from CMN_MST;
end;
```

This will probably result in a too_many_rows error because you can only select 1 row at a time using this method.

I suggest you study some more PLSQL first.

Comment: How to execute this proceudre [ exec DEL ? ]

Comment: http://plsql-tutorial.com/